# How to invoke a another method in main() method to display one array grouped under second one

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

I want to create 3 methods, 2 to declare and initialize arrays. And 3rd to loop through the 2 arrays. I want to invoke the third method in main() to display each index of array2 grouped under array1 index. I hope I have put my question through clearly.

```
class Program
{
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   Program p = new Program();
   p.display(Carnivore, ZooMammals);
 }
 public void Mammals(ZooMammals[] category)
 {
  category = new ZooMammals[4];
  category[1] = new ZooMammals() {Category="Carnivorous", Attribute = new Attributes[2] };
  category[2] = new ZooMammals() { Category = "Carnivorous", Attribute= new Attributes[1] };
  category[3] = new ZooMammals() { Category = "Carnivorous", Attribute = new Attributes[3] };
 }
 public static void Carnivore(Attributes[] Carn)
 {
   Carn = new Attributes[3];
   Carn[0] = new Attributes() { Sex ="M", colour = "yellow",Name="Lion" };
   Carn[1] = new Attributes() { Sex ="F", colour = "yellow",Name="Cat"};
   Carn[2] = new Attributes() { Sex ="M", colour = "yellow",Name="Tiger"};

 }
 public static void display(Attributes[] Carn,ZooMammals[] category)
 {


      foreach (var a in category)
        {
           if (a == null) continue;
           Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", a.Category, a.Attribute);
        }
        foreach (var x in category.Carn)
        {
           if (x == null) continue;
           Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", x.Sex, a.colour, x.Name);
           Console.WriteLine(category[1].Carn[0]);
           Console.WriteLine(category[1].Carn[1]);
           Console.WriteLine(category[1].Carn[2]);
           Console.WriteLine(category[2].Carn[0]);
           Console.WriteLine(category[2].Carn[1]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
      }

   }
 public class Attributes
 {
    public string Sex;
    public string colour;
    public string Name;
  }
 public class ZooMammals
 {
        public string Category;
        public Attributes[] Attribute;
     }

}
```

Comment: So whats the hold up??

Comment: sorry i dint get it?

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: my problem is that I am unable to call methods and link them to each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
       Program p = new Program();
       p.display(Mammals(), Carnivore());
     }
     public ZooMammals[] Mammals()
     {
      ZooMammals[] category = new ZooMammals[4];
      category[1] = new ZooMammals() {Category="Carnivorous", Attribute = new Attributes[2] };
      category[2] = new ZooMammals() { Category = "Carnivorous", Attribute= new Attributes[1] };
      category[3] = new ZooMammals() { Category = "Carnivorous", Attribute = new Attributes[3] };
     return category; 
     }
     public Attributes[] Carnivore()
     {
       Attributes[] Carn = new Attributes[3];
       Carn[0] = new Attributes() { Sex ="M", colour = "yellow",Name="Lion" };
       Carn[1] = new Attributes() { Sex ="F", colour = "yellow",Name="Cat"};
       Carn[2] = new Attributes() { Sex ="M", colour = "yellow",Name="Tiger"};
      return Carn;
     }
```

This is where you are going wrong i feel. This can be done better by declaring two global arrays and just assigning values in the methods and using the same through out the code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try the global arrays approach.